# AG-GRID - Using restoreFilterModel works, but entire grid is redrawn before filter is restored

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I've gotten my grid to save & restore the filter using saveFilterModel and restoreFilterModel.  Once my httpRequest is complete, the grid is redrawn and "flashes", then the restoreFilterModel is applied.  So, functionally it's sound, but from a UX perspective this isn't desirable.  Is there a way to silently update row data without the grid refreshing like that?  Essentially the equivalent of "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" in Excel VBA/Macro.

My refresh function:

```
      function refreshData() {
          saveFilterModel();
          let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          httpRequest.open('GET', '**********');
          httpRequest.send();
          httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                  var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                  gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
                  gridOptions.api.updateRowData({force : true});
                  restoreFilterModel();
              }
          };
```

Gif of the behavior is provided (set to request data every 3 seconds for example)

[ag-grid_restoreFilterModel.gif](https://imgflip.com/gif/3lsa05)

Comment: I've found a "solution", but still not quite as elegant as I'd like.

I had to set rowAnimation = false

1) The flicker is almost negligible, but yet still there
2) I lose the animation, which I really, really liked

I'd like to leave my question open in hopes that someone has a better solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Set deltaRowDataMode=true in the gridOptions. This causes the grid to only apply changes for data that is different, instead of just replacing all of the data.
- Remove your call to updateRowData(). The setRowData() should be sufficient, and following that with updateRowdata({force: true}) is probably causing it to update twice.
- restore the filter model before applying the new data with setRowData(). If the filter model is different from the default filter model, setting the data first will cause a flash, as you see the data change due to the new filter.

Comment: Thank you!  The deltaRowDataMode did the trick.  I haven't yet worked through bullets 2 & 3 as #1 is a perfect solution.